# Sliding ViewPager use too much memory

Tags: android, memory, android-viewpager, dismiss

I used ViewPager in my Android project.
I have more than 40 pages and I want to use them in ViewPager.
But when i slide the second page from first page, the memory used by the program was increased.
This increase continued in other pages.
My destroy item function:

```
@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
```

And my instantiateItem function:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView list = new StickyListHeadersListView(MainPage.this);  
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        list.setLayoutParams(imageParams3);
        list.setAdapter(stickyBaseAdapter);
        LinearLayout mainPage = new LinearLayout(MainPage.this);
        mainPage.addView(list);
        container.addView(mainPage);
        return mainPage;
    }
```

I tried `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);` , but it was keep increasing.

How I kill other layouts?

Thanks in Advance.